# How can i fix this error undefined is not an object(evaluating'navigation.Navigate')?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am new to react native, working on a project I have completed all the screens of my project but when I want to navigate to a different screen I am getting this error on clicking the button instead of switching screen.
This is my app.js code

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import Cardlist from "./components/MainMenu";

export default function App() {
  return <Cardlist />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

This is my button screen, here I have created two buttons at the bottom of the  screen and when i press the button i am getting the error

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import CardView from "../CardView";
import LoginScreen from "../Login/login";
import ApplyLoan from "../MainPage/ApplyLoan";
import styles from "./styles";
import imgs from "./imgs";

function BtnScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.btncontainer}>
      <Button
        buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
        title="Login"
        onPress={() => navigation.Navigate("Login")}
      />

      <Button
        buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
        title="Apply Now"
        onPress={() => navigation.Navigate("Applynow")}
      ></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const Cardlist = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.button}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require("../../assets/images/123.jpeg")}
        />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flat}
        data={imgs}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <CardView card={item} />}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToAlignment={"start"}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        snapToInterval={Dimensions.get("window").height}
      />

      <BtnScreen />

      <NavigationContainer>
        <AuthStack.Navigator>
          <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <AuthStack.Screen name="Applynow" component={ApplyLoan} />
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Cardlist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navigation.navigate('Login')
```

instead of

```
navigation.Navigate('Login')
```

Modify your navigator so BtnScreen is inside AuthStack

```
 <AuthStack.Navigator initialRouteName="ButtonScreen">
       <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
       <AuthStack.Screen name="Applynow" component={ApplyLoan} />
       <AuthStack.Screen name="ButtonScreen" component={BtnScreen} />
       <AuthStack.Screen name="CardList" component={CardList} />
     </AuthStack.Navigator>
```

Comment: it is because your BtnScreen is not inside the AuthStack.Navigator. You can only use navigation.navigate within LoginScreen and ApplyLoan component. Please see updated answer to show you example. You can rearrange the screens to your desire